# Insert navigation drawer

Tags: android

I created a project that uses 3 activities: login, register and dashboard.
In the dashboard activity (That starts after login), I would like to insert a navigation drawer. 
I've tried in so many ways but after 1 second the dashboard activity starts, closes, and returns to login.

Comment: We could help you if you provide a [mcve] of what you have, but Android Studio already has templates for NavigationView activities

Answer (score 0):

your app crashed and the problem in the dashboard activity

Comment: The app runs ok, as long as I do not want to change the dashboard activity in a navigation drawer.